# Importing UV coordinates

Tags: python, uv

I'm currently writing an import script/addon.

The file format is one vertex per line: `x, y, z, u, v`
With 3 lines for each triangle (no quads).

So far I've got vertex's, edges and faces all importing correctly.

Now I just need to import the UV coordinates for each vertex.

However I'm having trouble trying to find a way to do this.

The best result so far was copying code from the UV operator template, which gave me a UV Map, but it puts the whole model at one point.

Comment: You'll probably find looking at other import scripts helpful - in the obj script I see `me.tessface_uv_textures.new()` `blender_tface = me.tessface_uv_textures[0].data[i]` and `blender_tface.uv1 = verts_tex[face_vert_tex_indices[0]]`

Comment: I posted an example on blenderartists.org, which assumes you use polys/loops for your mesh import: [Importing UV coordinates](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?321210-Importing-UV-coordinates)

Comment: @CoDEmanX this is a rather good question. perhaps your post on BA could be summarized here.